# React - parent child communication. Isolated state

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a design question using react hooks. The idea is to have a tabbed dialog component where each tab displays different components, one of which is an image upload component. The image component should fetch images from an endpoint based on the props passed to it. It should display the images and allow the user to manage them in the panel. However, the dialog header is where the Save button is for the whole screen. My question is, how can this image component be told to save the image state it's tracking (but from the parent button)? Pseudocode:

```
function ItemComponent() {
 const itemData = fetchItemData(); 

 const itemDataSaveHandler = () => {
    // call api to save data in tab 1.
    // then notify the image component to save 
    // its image state. Then close dialog.
    setDialogOpen(false)
 }

const itemCancelHandler = () => {
  setDialogOpen(false)
}

 return (
 <>
  <HeaderComponent saveHandler={itemDataSaveHandler} cancelHandler={itemCancelHandler} />
   <TabOne>
     <SomeComponent /> 
   </TabOne>
   <TabTwo>
     <ImageUploadComponent key={itemData.someId} /> 
   </TabTwo>
 </>
   )
 }
```

I want the image uploader to do all the image work and I don't want to mix image state with the state in the first tab (omitted for brevity). It would seem easy if my image component had its own save button, but in this case it doesn't and it should depend on another save button higher up to notify it. It's not like I can call imageComponent.save() since it's a function. How can I make this communication between parent and child?

I hope this makes sense, and maybe it's much easier than I am imagining. My experience in React/JS is limited.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `useEffect` and a state.

**ItemComponent**

```
function ItemComponent() {
  const itemData = fetchItemData();
  const [saveImage, setSaveImage] = useState(false);

  const itemDataSaveHandler = () => {
    // call api to save data in tab 1.
    // then notify the image component to save
    // its image state. Then close dialog.
    setDialogOpen(false);
    setSaveImage(true);
  };

  const itemCancelHandler = () => {
    setDialogOpen(false);
  };

  const onSaveImageSuccess = () => setSaveImage(false);

  return (
    <>
      <HeaderComponent
        saveHandler={itemDataSaveHandler}
        cancelHandler={itemCancelHandler}
      />
      <TabOne>
        <SomeComponent />
      </TabOne>
      <TabTwo>
        <ImageUploadComponent
          key={itemData.someId}
          saveImage={saveImage}
          onSaveImageSuccess={onSaveImageSuccess}
        />
      </TabTwo>
    </>
  );
}
```

**Image Component**

```
const ImageUploadComponent = ({ saveImage, onSaveImageSuccess }) => {
  const saveImageApiCall = () => {
    // API call
    onSaveImageSuccess();
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (saveImage) {
      saveImageApiCall();
    }
  }, [saveImage]);

  return Component;
};
```

Comment: I typed this answer on mobile so any help with edit or code reformatting is much appreciated.

Comment: @Emile Bergeron Thanks Mate!